# Ruby regular expression - remove from a html string empty newlines

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to find a regexp in ruby that output a string after removing from the input string any br tag at the end of the string which is followed by nothing or followed by an empty space &nbsp

In practice:

```
line1<br />
line2<br />
&nbsp;
```

should become the output:

```
line1<br />
line2
```

The string

```
line1<br />
line2<br />
```

should become the output:

```
line1<br />
line2
```

It should work with the following variations for a br tag:

```
<br>
<br >
<br/>
<br /> ( my editor uses this one with an space between br and the closing > )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `<br\s?\/?>(?=$\n*&nbsp;|&nbsp;|\Z)(?:\n*&nbsp;)?`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhinFq/1)

Comment: I'll try to understand it and convert into a ruby regexp